# SQLAlchemy returns `list` instead of `Sequence[Row[_TP]]`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-typing

The type-hinting of the method `sqlalchemy.engine.result.Result.fetchall()` suggests the method is supposed to return a `Sequence[Row[_TP]]` but when I print `print(type(result_1.fetchall()))`, I get a `list`.
[image]

Is there anything I'm missing?

My code is the following:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine: sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "sqlite:///data_SQL/new_db.db", echo=False
    )

    with engine.connect() as connection:
        result_1: sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult = connection.execute(
            sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE batch = 'sdfg';")
        )
        data_fetched_1: sqlalchemy.Sequence = result_1.fetchall()
        print(type(data_fetched_1))
```

Comment: A list is a sequence, isn't it?

Comment: @JohnGordon PyCharm doesn't agree, when I type it as a list it says "Expected type `list`, got `Sequence` instead". Proof: https://i.imgur.com/bWf7tTa.png.

Comment: A list is a kind of sequence, but a sequence is not a kind of list.

Comment: How should I type-hint my variable then? Is sqalchemy.Sequence good?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows That's a database sequence object, not a container datatype.  I was thinking about [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence).

Comment: Yes I just realized, my bad!

Comment: Is there a way to type-hint a Sequence?

Comment: Typing isn't really my thing, but to judge from [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), the `Sequence` abc I linked earlier is the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list` is a subtype of the abstract base class [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes). You cannot annotate a variable with `list` and then assign a `Sequence` to it because that `Sequence` could be something other than a `list`, such as a `tuple` for example, which happens to also be a [subtype of `Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range).

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence


print(issubclass(list, Sequence))  # True
print(issubclass(tuple, Sequence))  # True
```

In general, if you expect your variable to behave like *any* sequence, i.e. support subscripting (via `__getitem__`) and all the other methods expected of the sequence protocol, you should annotate it as such, meaning with `collections.abc.Sequence`. But then you cannot expect it to support e.g. `list`-specific methods like `append`.

If you want to make *sure* you are dealing with a list, **every** `Sequence` can be turned into a list by simply calling the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) constructor on it (because `Sequence` is a subtype of `Iterable`).

More to the point, I am not sure where you are getting your type annotations for SQLAlchemy from, but they are likely outdated. My PyCharm shows the signature of `Result.fetchall` to return `list[Row]` and so do the latest official [`sqlalchemy-stubs`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy2-stubs/blob/v0.0.2a32/sqlalchemy-stubs/engine/result.pyi#L69). (Same for `Result.all` by the way.) So a variable of type `list` should definitely accept the output of that method and your type checker is just using wrong type stubs.

The good news is that when SQLAlchemy 2 finally drops, we will no longer have these issues because it will thankfully feature inline type annotations.

### PS

Oops, totally missed that version 2 has been out for a while now. Thanks to @sergenp for pointing it out. The [current annotations](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_2_0_4/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L1300) indeed show `Sequence[Row[_TP]]`.

Since the `Result` class is specified to inherit from [`ResultInternal[Row[_TP]]`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_2_0_4/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L887), which is parameterized by `_R` and its [`_allrows`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_2_0_4/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L523) method returns a `list[_R]`, the annotations are still technically correct. The `fetchall` method returns the output of the `_allrows` method. `list[Row[_TP]]` is a subtype of `Sequence[Row[_TP]]`.

It is best practice to declare the return type as *narrow* as possible, but in this case the developers did not. I can only speculate that they might plan to have `fetchall` return some other sequence object that is *not* a list in the future and to ensure stability of the API they annotated it with the broader type. You can always *narrow* the return type later maintaining backwards-compatibility, but you cannot *broaden* or *change* it to a different (not descendant) type later because that breaks backwards compatibility. But this is just guessing on my part.

Either way, as users of their API we must take their type hints at face value and expect whatever they say `fetchall` returns. We must not *assume* it returns a `list`, even though it does now. `_allrows` is a protected method and thus considered implementation detail.

The advice I gave in my original answer still holds: If you are fine with just any sequence, annotate your variable accordingly. If you need a list, convert the output of `fetchall` to a list explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean where do I get my type annotations from? I just did `pip install SQAlchemy` and I got them by hovering on the method? Is there another way of having them?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by SQLAlchemy 2 finally dropping, it seems like it is already here. Version of my sqlalchemy is 2.0.4, which is where I got my typing information from. And there is inline type annotations in it. Which doesn't show Result.fetchall returning List[], rather a Sequence. Yet the method it calls returns a List (see my answer)

Comment: @sergenp You are right, I totally missed that it has been already released. I don't know why they annotated it like this, but it is not wrong as I explained above. Since `_allrows` returns a `list`, it is technically correct to declare `fetchall` to return a `Sequence` because the former is a subtype of the latter. It is a strange choice because best practice is to annotate the return type as **narrow** as possible. But they must have their reasons. Maybe they plan to implement it differently to return some other `list`-like object.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Sorry, I mistakenly thought you used SQLAlchemy v1 because I missed the release of v2. The older major version had no inline type annotations and used stub files for typing. There was some confusion about which ones were correct and compatible with what specifically, which is why I assumed you had the wrong stubs. v2 has no ambiguity anymore, so you have to take their type hints at face value.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the source code,

```py
    def fetchall(self) -> Sequence[Row[_TP]]:
        """A synonym for the :meth:`_engine.Result.all` method."""

        return self._allrows()
```

fetchall just returns self._allrows()

And this is the function signature of self._allrows:

```py
(method) def _allrows() -> List[Row[_TP@Result]]
```

So that is why you're getting a type list

Comment: Interesting! I'm not sure I understand why these two functions are not coherent in their signature?? Is there a reason?

Comment: Yeah I don't get it either, feels like if your function just returns the result of another function, they should have the same return type

Comment: _"if your function just returns the result of another function, they should have the same return type"_ Not necessarily. The call to `_allrows` is an implementation detail of `fetchall`. They might change that at any point later and have `fetchall` return something else that is not a `list` but still a `Sequence`. Whether or not that is the case here I don't know.

Comment: What is an implementation detail? I'm not sure I understand.